# CakePHP email not working properly - how to track the error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I using cakephp email component. In my live server $this->Email->send() return success. but mail is not receiving. what is the problem?? i need to find whats the error ?
My controller not have any model this may cause any problem for emails ?

```
        $this->Email->from     = 'Mysitename <no-reply@mysite.com';
        $this->Email->to       =  'sample@gmail.com';
        $this->Email->subject  = "This is test";
        $this->Email->template = 'template_name'; 
        $this->Email->sendAs   = 'html'; 

        ob_start();
        if($this->Email->send())
        {
           $this->log(' Mail Success');
        }
        else
        {
          $this->log('Something broke in mail');    
        }
        ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Why using the `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` funcionts? You don't need them to EmailComponent work

Comment: Please paste your real code, even if you only changed the two lines to conceal email addresses. I highly doubt the code you have here with such egregious syntax errors will result in any mail being sent at all.

Comment: This is the code i am using..its working fine in my development server. and i not have any error in my template too. even though if i not passing any TO email id the log is display "Mail Success". I included my email component in that controller.

Comment: @Cake there is no way that is the actual code you are using as it would throw a PHP syntax error in the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set delivery to [debug](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1284/Class-Attributes-and-Variables#Debugging-Emails-1635) to see an output of your message to make sure it's fine:

```
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
```

And you also need to setFlash('email') to see the output in your view:

```
echo $this->Session->flash('email');
```

As far as emailing from a live server goes - there's a very good chance the server or IP is blacklisted and you'll need to get it to pass various checks before your sent messages can be received:

http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/debian/setting-up-spf-senderid-domain-keys-and-dkim.html